# Props validation for props' properties in React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-props

I can specify the proTypes of `classes` in a simple React component NewButton.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

const styles = () => ({
  button: {
    display: 'inline-flex',
  },
});

function NewButton(props) {
  const { classes } = props;

  return <Button className={classes.button} variant="outlined" />;
}

NewButton.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.shape({}).isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(NewButton);
```

But I got an error `'classes.button' is missing in props validation eslint(react/prop-types)` from [eslint-plugin-react](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/prop-types.md).

What's the proper way to specify the proTypes of `classes.button` as well?

Comment: What specifically is the warning you are getting for propTypes?

Comment: I have added the specific error message to my origin post.

Comment: Which version of react are you using? [This error came up prior to 7.12.3](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/issues/2134)

Comment: I am using eslint-plugin-react, v7.14.2.

Comment: If you use typescript, there are many clear solutions by now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is something like this:

```
NewButton.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.shape({
    button: PropTypes.shape({
      display: PropTypes.string.isRequired
    })
  }).isRequired,
};
```

Which, since YOU define that structure above in this file, and it's injected by you, I would argue this is pointless otherwise you'd be changing this shape every time you changed your styles.

You may consider eslint-ignoring this error and simply defining the top-level property.

This goes the same for the Material UI theme object - it's massive and you definitely wouldn't want to define that shape in every component that used their entire theme object (just to appease eslint)

It may feel bad doing this, but I've found that there are tradeoffs. The whole point of PropTypes (to me) is to define the expected properties to consumers of this file. `classes` is *defined by the file itself*.

Answer (score 0):

How about defining the propTypes for the classes object to accept any internal structure?

```
NewButton.propTypes = {
    classes: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.any).isRequired,
};
```

This way, you shouldn't need to change your linting rules.